nVidia Graphics Driver no longer available
I have been happily using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my PC for some time. Recently a major update was installed on reboot (black screen with Ubuntu logo and spinning wheel). I'm suddenly having all kinds of problems with my dual-monitor setup. I went to check the Additional Drivers app, but no nVidia driver packages are available. See screenshot. I was previously using the 545 nVidia metapackage. How can I reenable nVidia drivers? Limited Driver Options

This page seemed to have the relevant info: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation
The command

sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia:535

Reenabled all the available nVidia driver options. Hooray!
